# Examples of objects that are too large to be sets

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I'm studying Category Theory, and most books talk about objects that are "small" if they are not sets. In order to understand this, I went and read a bit on Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets (ETCS), which formulates new axioms for set theory a bit different to ZFC.

Yet, I was left wondering what are some example of objects that are indeed too big to be sets. I know the most obvious one, which is the class of all sets. What other objects aren't sets in ETCS?

Comment: I would guess categories like $\operatorname{Grp}$ would be "too big" to be sets. There is the notion of [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) to refer to collections that are "too big" to be sets.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas *Proper classes*, in fact. Classes include sets.